# Get nearest low and high values across multiple dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd

id = [1001, 1002, 1003]
a = [156, 224, 67]             
b = [131, 203, 61]          
c = [97, 165, 54]        
d = [68, 122, 50]
value = [71, 180, 66]

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':id, 'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c, 'd':d, 'value':value})
```

| id | **a** | **b** | **c** | **d** | **value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 156 | 131 | 97 | 68 | 71 |
| 1002 | 224 | 203 | 165 | 122 | 180 |
| 1003 | 67 | 61 | 54 | 50 | 66 |

For each row, I would like to evaluate columns **a-d** and within them identify the next lowest and next highest values, as compared to **value**. So in this example, the expected result would look like:

| id | a | b | c | d | value | nxt_low | nxt_high |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 156 | 131 | 97 | 68 | 71 | 68 | 97 |
| 1002 | 224 | 203 | 165 | 122 | 180 | 165 | 203 |
| 1003 | 67 | 61 | 54 | 50 | 66 | 61 | 67 |

I have tried creating a single column with a numpy array from **a-d** and trying to do some operations that way, but I'm not applying it correctly and have been unable to get the desired result. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get nearest low following code:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x < x[-1]].max(), axis=1)
```

output:

```
0     68
1    165
2     61
dtype: int64
```

get nearest low and high and make result to columns:

```
df[['nxt_low', 'nxt_high']] = df.apply(lambda x: [x[x < x[-1]].max(), x[x > x[-1]].min()], axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

`df`:

```
    id      a   b   c   d   value   nxt_low nxt_high
0   1001    156 131 97  68  71      68      97
1   1002    224 203 165 122 180     165     203
2   1003    67  61  54  50  66      61      67
```

If `id` is nearest low or high, modify code a bit.

```
df[['nxt_low', 'nxt_high']] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: [x[x < x[-1]].max(), x[x > x[-1]].min()], axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
cols = ['a','b','c','d']
df2 = df[cols].sub(df['value'],axis=0)
df = (df.assign(nxt_low = df.where(df2.lt(0)).max(axis=1),
nxt_high = df.where(df2.gt(0)).min(axis=1)))
```

Output:

```
     id    a    b    c    d  value  nxt_low  nxt_high
0  1001  156  131   97   68     71     68.0      97.0
1  1002  224  203  165  122    180    165.0     203.0
2  1003   67   61   54   50     66     61.0      67.0
```